# How is the for loop in printing the spaces are not inverted yet it prints inversely?

Tags: c++, loops

I have this code snippet which prints a basic pyramid. It works but I can't explain or understand the for loop in printing the spaces:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int rows;
    cout << "Enter number of rows: ";
    cin >> rows;


    for(int i=1 ; i <= rows ; i++){


        //for printing the spaces per row
        for(int j = i; j <= rows; j++){

            cout << " ";
        }

        // printing the asterisk per row
        for(int j=1 ; j <= i*2-1 ; j++){

            cout << "*";

        }

        // adding a new line after each loop
        cout << endl;;
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the for loop of printing the spaces, how does it print inversely if it is stated that `j = i`. What I understand is it should print on what the value of i. For example, if `rows is = 5` and it is on for loop, it should begin with 1 right? then why does it print more than 1 spaces in its first loop?

Sorry for the dumb question I'm a beginner.

Comment: To explore how this works, single step debugging might be enlightening.

Comment: If rows = 3, first time it will print three spaces (j=1,2,3), then two spaces (j=2,3) and then one space (j=3).

Comment: With your example of `rows = 5;`, for `i = 1`: `for (j = 1; j <= 5; ++j)` -> 5 spaces, for `i = 2`: `for (j = 2; j <= 5; ++j)` -> 4 spaces, for `i = 3`: `for (j = 3; j <= 5; ++j)` -> 3 spaces, and so on.

Comment: `cout << string(rows-i+1, ' ') << string(i*2-1, '*') << "\n";`

Comment: Given that `i` is 1 and `rows` is 5, explain to yourself why `for(int j = 1; j <= 5; j++) { cout << " "; }`  should print just one space.

Comment: This question may need more clarity.  Many comments trying to guess how a for statement might be unclear to someone.  But there's no explanation why the poster thinks that only one space should be printed in the loop in question.

Comment: `for(int i=1 ; i <= rows ; i++)`: all the loops are one-based, for no reason. In C++, please prefer to use zero-based loops, like in `for(int I=0 ; i < rows ; i++)`. You will have less problems in the future, and avoid confusing other programmers.

Answer (score 1):

The explaination for it is in the code itself but still if you need more explaination than here it is.

The below code is responsible for printing spaces in your code.

```
for(int i=1 ; i <= rows ; i++){
    for(int j = i; j <= rows; j++){

        cout << " ";
    }
    //...... other code......
 }
```

Now in your first iteration of outer loop (loop of i), when i = 1, the inner loop starts from i which is 1 and goes till rows (we assume it 5). so 5 time

```
 cout<<" ";
```

will get executed. Than now in next iteration of outer loop, value of I will be 2 and loop will go from 2 to 5 which means 4 times cout will get called and it will repeat till the end of your outer loop.

> What I understand is it should print on what the value of i.

to clarify this, it will print i times if your code will be

```
 for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
```

Hope this is what you were asking and this helps you to understand your code.